# Why does my JS script work but not the same C#?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have recently started playing working in unity3d and I run into the following problem following a tutorial.

The tutorial used unity-javascript but I prefer to use C#.

I was given the following code in Javascript

```
function Shoot() {
    var bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, 
                             transform.Find("BulletSpawn").position,
                             transform.Find("BulletSpawn").rotation);
    bullet.rigidbody.AddForce(transform.forward * bulletSpeed);                      
}
```

and rewrote it in C#-code as

```
    void Shoot() {
    GameObject bullet;
    bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, 
                         transform.Find("BulletSpawn").position,
                         transform.Find("BulletSpawn").rotation) as GameObject;
    bullet.rigidbody.AddForce(transform.forward * bulletSpeed); 
}
```

My problem is that the JS script works but with my C# code I get

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

on the line `bullet.rigidbody.AddForce(transform.forward * bulletSpeed);`

Any suggestions of what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Is all the rest exactly the same? Where do you initialize bulletSpeed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return type of `Instantiate` is a `Transform` and cannot be casted directly to `GameObject` (`as GameObject`)

Your code should be:

```
void Shoot() {
    Transform bullet;
    bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, 
                         transform.Find("BulletSpawn").position,
                         transform.Find("BulletSpawn").rotation);
    bullet.rigidbody.AddForce(transform.forward * bulletSpeed); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, always these tiny problems when learning a new framework!